# MYSQL re-fetch error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, forms, syntax

I just got error from MYSQL saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

After submiting form on the page i got that messenge.

Any ideas?

Here is sql code that i used

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member ".
                "WHERE termId='$term'  ".
                "AND year='$year' ".
                "AND familyId='$familyId' order by memberId";
        $rs =  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please die($sql) and post result.

Comment: You should be escaping your parameters if they come from user input or you will be vulnerable to SQL injection (http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Comment: SELECT * FROM member_class WHERE termId='2' AND year='' AND familyId='' order by memberId

Comment: @user1079810 - That means $year and $familyid are empty.

Comment: @AVD - perhaps, but that doesn't explain the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escapes special characters in a string.

```
$term=mysql_real_escape_string($term);

if(isset($year,$familyid,$term))
{
  $myear=intval($year);  
  $mfamilyid=intval($familyid);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE termId='$term' 
            AND year='$myear' 
            AND familyId='$mfamilyId' 
            order by memberId";

  $rs =  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to replace single quotes in your query with *backticks* as follows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member ".
        "WHERE termId=`$term` ".
        "AND year=`$year` ".
        "AND familyId=`$familyId` order by memberId";
$rs =  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It seems very, very unlikely that the OP is expecting valid *column names* in `$term`, `$year`, etc., which is what is implied by suggesting the OP use MySQL's identifier quotes (backticks) around those variables...

Answer (score 0):

Your final SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM member_class WHERE termId='2' AND year='' AND familyId='' order by memberId
```

I suspect at least familyID, maybe also year are number fields, so this is a syntax error.

Comment: Under what version of MySQL is comparing a numeric field to an empty string a *syntax* error?  `1 = ''` and `1.0 = ''`, for example, are simply zero (MySQL's representation of *false*).